# How to clone SD card from 16G to 16G if sizes slightly differeent?

Tags: sd-card, win32diskimager

I have 16G source SD card with 14.51G of actual size and I need to duplicate it to another 16G SD card with actual size 14.41G.

I have found another question: [Cloning SD card to different size SD card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4734/cloning-sd-card-to-different-size-sd-card). This question has been answered but all answers are actual for Linux.

However, I need to execute duplication on Windows computer without any access to Raspberry Pi. All I have now is Win 32 Disk Imager which generates error message due to lack of size.

Is there any other Windows based size tolerant SD card cloning tool?

Comment: Excuse me for asking, but why do you need to do the duplication on a Windows machine? You could do this on your RPi.

Comment: Using the Microsoft Windows operating system does not belong to Raspberry Pi. Please ask in a MS Windows forum.

Comment: Use the RaspiOS built in "SD Card Copier" tool with the SDCard you want to clone onto in a USB reader. The built-in copier doesn't care whether the cards have the same capacity as it's only copying used space.

Comment: https://florianmuller.com/quickly-resize-and-shrink-raspberry-pi-sd-card-image-on-macos looks to give you at least a piece in terms of resizing a IMG file of an SD card to something smaller. With this smaller IMG file you can use your normal tools to write it to a smaller SD card.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT possible on Windows but it can be done on the Pi itself using the SD Card Copier included in Raspbian.

[Backup image of SD Card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103991/8697) describes how to produce a small installable image from a running Pi.
This runs on the Pi, but the can produce an image on a Windows (or any other) computer - I do this to my Mac.
This initially is a little involved to setup, but subsequently is fast and easy.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting solution would be: download [Knoppix](http://knopper.net/) (or any of many other linux live-CD distributions), burn it to CD or DVD (or use any of various tools to write it to USB or flash media), boot from it, and then use that to copy from the one SD, and then to create comparable filesystems on the other SD.